# MgTwitterEngine Iphone

Tags: ios4

Hello
 I am using mgtwitterengine in iphone to call twitter API. I want to retrive followers name
in my iphone. 
I used textfield.text=[_engine getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:YES]; but it is not showing correct result. it only show some alphabets...

could anyone tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

you are using 
`NSLog(@"%@",[_engine getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:YES]);`

`getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus` not responding the result, it returns connection identifier which is `DF387EE5-05CE-40E3-A12D-4D016C581233` in your case

your API response will come in this method
`- (void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)identifier`
this is delegate method you have to add this in your class.

Comment: hello userInfoReceived delegate method is not called so any idea?

Comment: hello userInfoReceived delegate method not called so any idea

Comment: you will get response in this method ... make sure you have set delegate method...

Comment: ok Is there any way or any delegate method to get all email id of friends using MGTwitterEngine?any idea?

Comment: we cannot get email ids of friends

Answer (score 0):

[_engine getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:YES];
use like this it may help you, i got the values and printing on console

Comment: if its not working to you tell me because by that i got it and printing on console with nslog if you know how delegate of following can you tell me

Comment: I used NSLog(@"%@",[_engine getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:YES]); IT shows this output on console ....Request DF387EE5-05CE-40E3-A12D-4D016C581233 succeeded....But I want to retrieve followers name in UITextView..???

Comment: @good_guy I am using the same .. it give proper output but now it return null response .. there is some API issue... can you please tell me how I get the follower list .... check my question http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/9d14524e9a8b6671?pli=1 .. and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328510/error-403-while-getfollowers-twitter-iphone-mgtwitterengine

Comment: my problem is solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328510/error-403-while-getfollowers-twitter-iphone-mgtwitterengine

Comment: @Amit Battan, happy to hear it, Thank you, have a great day