# Error 403 while getFollowers : Twitter Iphone MGTwitterEngine

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, twitter

I am using Twitter-OAuth-iPhone https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone
I am calling [twitterObj getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:NO] for getting my friend list which was working fine. But from last two days
its giving me the 403 error.

```
-- Twitter Request FD751461-39C4-4EAB-A0F7-D1ED262B19EA failed with
error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be
completed. (HTTP error 403.)"
```

As twitter api wiki 403 is due to crossing the limit of updates and DM

but here in getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus Why this error occurring and even list is not comes next day giving same 403 error.

Thanks
Amit Battan

Comment: these are URLs one is working and other not `https://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.xml` working fine,    . . . .


`https://twitter.com/statuses/followers.xml` not working giving 403 error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it is solved now

I change

```
#define TWITTER_DOMAIN          @"twitter.com"
```

to

```
#define TWITTER_DOMAIN          @"api.twitter.com/1"
```

in MGTwitterEngine.m

Comment: Worked like a treat, or rather a tweet!! Changing this does not affect the rest MGTwitterEngine.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this! it helped me a bunch! I would like to add to anyone coming to this for answers that while calling out with this method works you still have to make adjustments elsewhere....

First you have to make sure you parse this correctly in your dictionary .... This is the one case I found "user" is NOT the main array. In fact there is no array it is just strings for example in "statuses received you want to call out @"user" @"screen_name" with retrieving your followers which is under "userInfoRecieved" you will just parse the string @"screen_name" .

At least this is how it worked for me!

One thing I would love to find out is how to retrieve more then 100. I have almost 1,000 followers and can only see 100.

I would also like to know how to retrieve the users I follow so I can place that into a popOverController with a tableview whenever a texfield is pressed so you can easily @Mention a friend!!!

@Amit if you have anything to add or any solutions for those few things I have stated please jump in and enlighten me.

Comment: check this discussion http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/9d14524e9a8b6671?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

this url not work , and not response , its show the errorhttps://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.xml working fine, . . . .  https://twitter.com/statuses/followers.xml

change it

## define TWITTER_DOMAIN          @"twitter.com"

to

## define TWITTER_DOMAIN          @"api.twitter.com/1"

in you .m class of twitter engine