# sending the tweet in twitter in iphone app, getting the request failed error

Tags: iphone

Iam developing Iphone applications. i have integrated twitter in to my app, it is good up to login into twitter (authentication), but when we call method [engine sendUpdate] (for sending tweet), it says the follwing error has occurred.

Request CFE50DC4-02A0-46C1-BFF9-3F1F2E325C29 failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=404 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 404.)"

Please tell me the solution.

Thanks

Comment: The votes on your questions are ... questionable.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to upgrade your application to use the correct URLs.

In the case of API resource URLs, you want URLs that look like https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json

In the case of OAuth negotiation URLs, you want URLs that look like
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2359
(I did not check it personally, Posting so that it may help others)

...i checked, (worked for me)

Replace: #define TWITTER_DOMAIN          @"twitter.com"

With:    #define TWITTER_DOMAIN          @"api.twitter.com/1"

in MGTwitterEngine.m

Similar Post: [Error 403 while getFollowers : Twitter Iphone MGTwitterEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328510/error-403-while-getfollowers-twitter-iphone-mgtwitterengine)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 404 is a Not Found error, so it's likely that the URL you're using to send a tweet is incorrect.

Check what you have in your code with the twitter documentation at http://dev.twitter.com

Answer (score 0):

### Version 1 of the API is now deprecated. This document may describe an outdated version of the API. Please move to [Version 1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) of the API as soon as possible.

Go through this document.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/direct_messages/new

Point to be noted

- Api format should me json
- Api version v1.1
- sender and receiver should follow each other.

Example Request

**POST** : https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json
**POST Data** : text=hello&screen_name=rajneesh071